# Best Way to Manage Derived Properties

Tags: swift, core-data, nsnotificationcenter, key-value-observing, mediator

I have a couple custom NSManagedObjects that have various relationships between each other. Below is a very simplified example. In production there should ~10 instances of A, >= 10k instances of B, and <30 instances of C.

First, I'm trying to track the sum of `B.value` for specific categories in `A`. Second, I'm tracking the sum of `B.value` in `C` if `B.date` is between `C.startDate` and `C.endDate`. `C` instances are in a linked list style representing sequential windows in time.

If `B.value` changes manually going to `A` and `C` is fairly simple and updating the cached value in each. Updating the date in `B` is a little tougher as I'd have to search through the list and update it.

With all of this in mind, I've been trying to determine **what is the best way in core data to keep these cached values up to date?** My current thought is a mediator pattern, NotificationCenter, or KVO. Mediator pattern is not super flexible but would work. NotificationCenter seems ideal, however I'm not sure how to ensure that all instances of `C` are always in memory and subscribed to the publisher. KVO seems solid, but it doesn't seem to report edits for objects already in to-many relationships. **What is the best way to keep these objects in sync with each other in the most Core data-esc way?**

```
+---------+            +--------+            +---------+
|A        |            |B       |            |C        |
+---------+            +--------+            +---------+
|totalCatA| <------->> |category| <<-------> |total    |
|totalCatB|            |date    |            |startDate|
+---------+            |value   |            |endDate  |
                       +--------+            |prevC    |
                                             |nextC    |
                                             +---------+
```